# Widget style theme color keyword

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I am using this to set background color of a widget:

```
self.setStyleSheet('QLineEdit { background-color: gray; }')
```

Now i want instead of `'gray'` write a keyword (something like `*button*`) which puts a color that is defined for buttons by the current theme. Is there such a keyword, or i have to use `QApplication.palette().button().color()` and put the color into the stylesheet by myself?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [PaletteRole](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html#paletterole):

```
QLineEdit { background-color: palette(button); }
```